# Haskell adding an element to a list via recursion

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm attempting to understand lists in Haskell and I've ran into something i'm unsure on. Is it possible to iterate through a loop and on each iteration add an item to a list ? for the purpose of the question i wrote the following code:

```
list = []
addNumbers 0 = return ()
addNumbers n =
 do
    print n
    n : list
    addNumbers (n-1)
```

I thought that this would work but it seems to give the error "Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’". I'm not quite sure why this error is coming up as there is no input or output being asked for from the user. I thought it may have been to do with the "print n" but it doesn't seem to work without that line.

Cheers in advance for any help

Comment: Typically in Haskell you would split the printing of the numbers (impure operation) from creating such a list (pure). If you were just debugging with the print statement, you can use something like Debug.Trace to cheat the typechecker (again, for debugging purposes only). http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Debugging#Debug_prints_with_Debug.Trace

Comment: You're mixing the `IO` monad from `print` and the List monad in the same binding! Remember that `a <- something` is just sugar for `something >>= \a ->`, and it needs to have very particular types as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not do what you think it does, in Haskell everything is immutable (once it has been given a value, that value cannot change).  What you might be trying to do is:

```
addNumbers :: Int -> IO [Int]
addNumbers 0 = return []
addNumbers n = do print n
                  ns <- addNumbers (n-1)
                  return (n:ns)
```

Then in the interpreter you'll get

```
ghci> addNumbers 3
3
2
1
[3, 2, 1]
ghci>
```

Pay careful attention to the signature of `addNumbers`, it accepts an `Int` and returns a list of `Int`'s encapsulated by the IO monad.  It has to be encapsulated by the IO monad because the call to print returns `()` in the IO monad and without that then the value won't be printed.

If you just want a list of `Int`'s prepended to a list then you can easily do

```
foo 0 = [0]
foo n = n:foo (n-1)
```

Comment: I've been playing around with this and it works perfectly. Just another little question, I've tried to add in an if statement. So if the number is divisible by 3 then it gets added to the list, if not it just takes one away. It doesn't seem to like the ns <- addNumbers (n-1) within an if statement.

Comment: @Jordan Replace the `return (n:ns)` with ``if n `mod` 3 == 0 then return (n:ns) else return (tail ns)``. You don't need to run `addNumbers` under an `if` for this. (And watch out because this can try to remove an element from the empty list)

Comment: Thank you chi, is there any reason i'm unable to call "length" on the output? I thought this created a list. But if i remove the print from the randomusername's code and call "length (addNumbers 3)" it gives an error. Any idea?

Comment: @Jordan You have a type mismatch: ``length`` has type ``[a] -> Int``, but your list has type ``IO [Int]``. Try ``fmap length $ addNumbers 3``.